# How do I use wget to get a file with a specific name?

Tags: wget, firefox

I'm using bash on Amazon Linux.

When I visit the following URL in a browser, https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US, I get a file, firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2.  However, when I use wget, the file that downloasd has an "index.html" in the title, even though it looks like the same file.  So I tried

```
wget -r --no-parent --reject "index.html*" -nH --cut-dirs=7 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US"
```

but now no file gets downloaded.  How can I download the file using wget (or some other command line tool) and get the file to be titled the same way it is when I visit that URL in a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, you want to trust the server name being sent in the headers, without that directive `wget` will use the file name in the URL...

`wget "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US" --trust-server-names`

Of course, for that to work, all servers need to send a file name for whatever file is being sent/generated.  Some scripts don't do this - if that is the case, you'll still get "index.html" that is actually the file.

What you do in that case is use the `-O` output option, and specify the desired filename on your end

`wget "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US" -O latest-firefox.tar.bz2`

Of course you need to know what file type it is, etc. for this part to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [cliget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/) addon for `firefox`. After pressing on the link it will generate a `curl` command under `Download with cURL`. In this case it would be something like this:

`curl --header 'Host: ftp.mozilla.org' --header 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0' --header 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' --header 'Accept-Language: en,de;q=0.5' --header 'Cookie: optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1495381484085r0.16482844406273445; optimizelySegments=%7B%22245984388%22%3A%22false%22%2C%22246002457%22%3A%22search%22%2C%22246073289%22%3A%22none%22%2C%22246073290%22%3A%22ff%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D' --header 'DNT: 1' --header 'Connection: keep-alive' --header 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' 'https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/56.0.1/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2' -o 'firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2' -L`

Comment: Thanks.  Here you are hard-coding "firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2".  Why, when I download the file in a browser does it get a different file name ("firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2") then when I use wget?

Comment: I don't hardcode it, `cliget` created that command. Another user has already posted an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **`curl`** tool:

```
curl -Os "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US/firefox-56.0.1.tar.bz2"
```

> **`-O`**, **`--remote-name`**
>                 Write  output  to a local file named like the remote file we get. (Only the file part of the remote file is used,
>                 the path is cut off.)